# How to Deploy Nuget in Prerelease View With Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am setting up a DevOps release pipeline that is triggered off a build pipeline.

The build pipeline uses the Nuget Pack to create a nupkg file and publishes it as an Artifact.

The release pipeline is triggered and Nuget Push is used to deploy to the DevOps feed.

I have found the “Promote package to Release View” task, but how do I get the Package Version to provide in the step?

I should note that, in the build pipeline, the Nuget pack step uses the build number for the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the build pipeline uses `Nuget pack` with the build number for the version. So, you just need to enable the CD (Continuous deployment trigger) for your release pipeline. Then use the predefined variable `Build.BuildNumber` in the “`Promote package to Release View`” task.

Select the package that you want to promote. Multiple packages may be supplied separated with a comma or semicolon. Note you may use either the name of the package or its GUID.

[image]